# Object files to different executables

Tags: makefile

I have objects files like:

> task1.o task2.o task3.o task4.o tasks.o comm.o

I need to link every of task*.o with two of tasks.o comm.o.
manually it looks like:

> gcc -Wall -o task1 task1.o tasks.o comm.o
>
> gcc -Wall -o task2 task2.o tasks.o comm.o

So in result i will have 4 executables, task1.exe etc. but when i try to do this with makefile like:

```
TASKS= task1 task2 task3 task4
TASK_OBJECTS= task1.o task2.o task3.o task4.o
OBJS_SOURCES= tasks.c comm.c
OBJS= tasks.o comm.o
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -Wall -c -o 

all: $(TASKS)

$(TASKS): $(TASK_OBJECTS) $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(TASK_OBJECTS) $(OBJS)
$(TASK_OBJECTS): %.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@ $<
$(OBJS): %.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $@ $<
clean:
    rm -rf *.o task1 task2 task3 task4
```

I get:

```
gcc -Wall -c -o  task1.o task1.c
gcc -Wall -c -o  task2.o task2.c
gcc -Wall -c -o  task3.o task3.c
gcc -Wall -c -o  task4.o task4.c
gcc -Wall -c -o  tasks.o tasks.c
gcc -Wall -c -o  comm.o comm.c
gcc -o task1 task1.o task2.o task3.o task4.o tasks.o comm.o
```

instead of

```
gcc -Wall -c -o  task1.o task1.c
gcc -Wall -c -o  task2.o task2.c
gcc -Wall -c -o  task3.o task3.c
gcc -Wall -c -o  task4.o task4.c
gcc -Wall -c -o  tasks.o tasks.c
gcc -Wall -c -o  comm.o comm.c
gcc -o task1 task1.o tasks.o comm.o
gcc -o task2 task2.o tasks.o comm.o
gcc -o task3 task3.o tasks.o comm.o
gcc -o task4 task4.o tasks.o comm.o
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
$(TASKS): $(TASK_OBJECTS) $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(TASK_OBJECTS) $(OBJS)
```

You're constructing *each* executable from *all* objects. Instead, you should use a static pattern rule (like the one you already use for `$(TASK_OBJECTS)`):

```
$(TASKS): % : %.o $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

(Note that `$^` is the automatic variable for "all prerequisites".)

Comment: Oh, it Works! =) after hours of trying it finally works, thanks a lot, this answer is a great source of material to read/search/try on makefiles, thanks again!

Comment: And one more to make it clear, it all looks like
Source of objects: which word to take: search for word of previous+".o" and in command line do something with the result-prerequisit(it calls that, right?)